# Add Build Step in Team Services for Creating a Zip File

Tags: command-line, zip, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The version of Team Services lacks a utility task type for creating an archive. How can I achieve the same effect by using a command line, or any other type of build steps? What I want to do is to create a .zip file for the build output for my project.

Comment: Do you success creating a zip file through Archive Files task in build?

Answer (score 2):

Team Services sprint 102 introduces a new build task: Archive Files, that you can create a zip file (specify zip for archive type parameter of Archive Files task.

[image]
You can refer to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/07/12/archive-files-build-task-for-team-services/) blog.

On the other hand, there are many [extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=zip&target=VSTS&sortBy=Relevance) that can achieve your requirement too.